# File reading but skips one character

Tags: c++

I am trying to read file through my program. I have done all most whole stuff other than one thing, that why my program skips the first character of file. I am pasting here selected code.

```
  ifstream inFile;
  char inFileName[] = "inFile.txt";
  inFile.open(inFileName, ios::in);

  char name[20], salary[20];
  char c;  

  while((c = inFile.get()) != EOF){     
     inFile >> name >> salary; 
  }
```

Whereas first word in file is,

```
Aamir
```

But my program prints

```
amir
```

Please guide me for this problem.
Also I want to know one more thing that what other condition I can give in while loop?

Thanks

Comment: When you call `inFile.get()`, it reads a character from the file. Then `infile >> name >> salary` starts from the next characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did write this code

```
while((c = inFile.get()) != EOF){     
     inFile >> name >> salary; 
  }
```

We can see very easily that you are reading first character here

```
while((c = inFile.get()) != EOF)
```

After that you are reading rest of the here

```
{     
   inFile >> name >> salary; 
}
```

Alternatively, my suggestion is you should while loop like to read whole file including first character

```
while(inFile >> name >> salary){
           //All stuff here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This block does exactly what you say you want to avoid:

```
while((c = inFile.get()) != EOF){     
     inFile >> name >> salary; 
  }
```

It is plain to see that you read one character, then read the rest.  You throw away the first character.  Stop doing that.  Instead, just say `while (inFile >> name >> salary) {...}`.

Comment: Thanks dear @john Zwinck for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

inFile.get() would read a character, and a following inFile would read next character.